# Cannot run script with node server.js

Tags: node.js

I can run code with just typing node then code, but with node server.js I can't run it. Nothing happens.

[image]

[image]
node --version returns
v9.4.0

Comment: Don't post text as image. If you already have text, feel free to add image.

Comment: Try reinstalling node. What's there inside your server.js? Minimal example only.

Comment: I tried it like 10 times

Comment: server.js doesnt matter its not working even with a  js file just console.log inside

Comment: Please paste the text of server.js into your question and format it appropriately here as code.  We can't help you without seeing the code you're trying to run in your question.

Comment: If the contents of server.js doesn't matter, then reinstall node as it can be nothing else besides that.  If the reinstall isn't working, then perhaps you have something else in your path besides what you're reinstalling.